# Maven error: Unable to get resource / Server redirected too many times

Tags: maven, blacklist

Our proxy went down and I tried to update dependencies with Maven while it was off.
Since then I can't download anything with Maven.
I get this error for everything.
I tried -U option, deleting my local repository and tried different Maven version (2.0.9, 2.2.1) but it doesn't work.
Any idea how to solve this?

Earlier it also said 'repository will be blacklisted' to all of them.

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.1/maven-compiler-plugin-2.1.pom

[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.1'
 from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): 
Error transferring file: Server redirected too many  times (20)
  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.1

from the specified remote repositories:
  jboss-snapshot (http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
  JBoss Repo (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2),
  spring-maven-snapshot (http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot),
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.external (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external),
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.snapshot (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/snapshot),
  jboss (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2),
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.release (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release),
  jboss-snapshot-plugins (http://snapshots.jboss.org/maven2),
  com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone (http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone),
  jboss-plugins (http://repository.jboss.com/maven2)


        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:228)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:90)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:558)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: Unable to download the artifact from any repository
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.manager.DefaultWagonManager.getArtifact(DefaultWagonManager.java:404)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.resolver.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:216)
        ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how this solved it but I changed my password (domain/proxy) and now it works.

Comment: +1, fixed it for me. My password was due to change today and the proxy had stopped accepting maven already.

Answer (score 7):

I got the same error with Windows ISA proxy. 
I had to put my Windows domain name and username in ~/.m2/settings.xml like this:

```
<username>DOMAIN\USERNAME</username>
```

Comment: I had the same problem behind a squid 2.7 proxy that normally serves Windows hosts. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4):

I had same problem.

The problem is 'domain' in file settings.xml

```
<proxy>
 ...
  <username>DOMAIN\user</username>
 ...
</proxy>
```

DOMAIN is optional if you launch maven in Microsoft Systems but it is mandatory if you launch maven in UNIX systems with domain authentication and remapped user (user home is in /home/DOMAIN/user), I found this trick in empiric way.

Answer (score 1):

Something that happened to me was that when I installed Maven, it added proxy information in ~/.m2/settings.xml.  I don't have a proxy, so I'm not sure where it came from, but that prevented me from being able to download anything.  After removing the proxy info, downloads were successful.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a proxy server section, but want to connect to a repository on the intranet you can add an exclusion list: `<nonProxyHosts>localhost|repoHost<nonProxyHosts>`