# Spring maven error

Tags: model-view-controller, spring, maven-2

I'm using spring MVC with maven to develop a web application, but when I update my dependencies I get this message:

```
5/6/10 10:09:50 AM CEST: Build errors for amundsen.web; org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.1:resources (default-resources) on project amundsen.web: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.1:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Unable to get dependency information for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:maven-plugin:2.4.1: Failed to process POM for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:maven-plugin:2.4.1: Non-resolvable parent POM org.apache:apache:6 for org.apache.maven:maven-parent:13: Failed to resolve POM for org.apache:apache:6 due to The repository system is offline and the requested artifact is not locally available at /home/waleed/.m2/repository/org/apache/apache/6/apache-6.pom
  org.apache:apache:pom:6

from the specified remote repositories:
  plexus.snapshots (http://oss.repository.sonatype.org/content/repositories/plexus-snapshots, releases=false, snapshots=true),
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2, releases=true, snapshots=false)
```

My Maven dependencies are:

```
    <!-- Junit -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency> <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet.jstl.version}</version> </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${servlet-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--<dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    --><!--<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    --><dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.taglibs.standard</artifactId>
        <version>${standard-taglib.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <!--
        <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version> </dependency>
    -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.commons.collections</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Compile dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.springsource.org.apache.log4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring (3.0) -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.aop</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.context</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.context.support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.beans</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.springframework.transaction</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core-tiger</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-security-core-tiger.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude 2.0.x spring dependencies -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-support</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency> 
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-dbc.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>


    <!--
        <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        hibernate-dependencies is a pom, not needed for hibernate-core
        </dependency>
    -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>${jta.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>${antlr.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql-connector-java.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--


        <dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId> <version>1.5.6</version>
        </dependency>
    --><!-- concrete Log4J Implementation for SLF4J API-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you defined a dependencyManagement in your parent pom? Which repositories do you use? (Snapshots ?)

Comment: Did you resolve your problem? I'm facing the same here!

Answer (score 1):

The build is not failing because of one of your dependencies, it's failing because of one of the dependencies of the `maven-resources-plugin`. More precisely, Maven is not able to resolve `org.apache:apache:pom:6` which **is** available in central though:

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/apache/6/apache-6.pom

Are you using m2eclipse? Is it configured to run offline (as the trace seems to suggest)?  Or could this be related to [MNGECLIPSE-1802](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-1802)?

Try to run maven on the command line, it should work and allow to workaround the issue with m2eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is not able to resolve org.apache:apache:pom:6 as it's working offline.
 When working in offline mode, the dependencies not already in the local repository will be inaccessible.

Try to run maven from command prompt and examine the current configurations

Answer (score 0):

You are under a proxy?

Try to config mvn proxy.

I was with the same problem and configuring properly the proxy on maven, all works!

Check this post:
[Maven error: Unable to get resource / Server redirected too many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499045/maven-error-unable-to-get-resource-server-redirected-too-many-times)

Regards